# UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell default contentOffset

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

In my app I have a **tableView** which contains several cells with **UICollectionView**, The layout of UICollectionView is custom and set in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

In **prepare** method of **collectionViewLayout** I set a default contentOffset to collectionView.

But this contentOffset only works for visible table cells and when I scroll tableview other cells do not have this `default content offset`.

How to fix this issue ?

```
override func prepare() {
    guard cache.isEmpty, let collectionView = collectionView else {
        return
    }

    // ...
    // Prepare cell attributes and add to cache array
    // ...

    collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 100, y:0)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following solution to fix this issue, Set content offset after a few milliseconds delay fixed this issue.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(10), execute: {
    collectionView.contentOffset = self.initialContentOffset!
})
```

But I think this isn't the best solution but I couldn't find another solution to fix this issue